# Renaming a single element in a list transforms the names of the other elements to `<NA>`

Tags: r

I have an unnamed list like this one:

```r
foo <- list(1, 2)
foo
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
```

If I try to name only one element of this list, then the other name becomes `<NA>`:

```r
names(foo)[2] <- "some_name"
foo
#> $<NA>
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $some_name
#> [1] 2
```

But having a mix of named and unnamed elements is possible in a list:

```r
list(1, some_name = 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $some_name
#> [1] 2
```

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139570/rename-list-items) only show how to rename all the elements of a list, or how to rename some elements of a list that is already fully named.

How can I rename a single element of a list without transforming the other ones to `<NA>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't give a name, it uses the name of `""` but when you use `names()[2]<-` it fills missing values with NA. You could get what you want by setting all values to "" first.

```
foo <- list(1, 2)
names(foo) <- rep("", length(foo))
names(foo)[2] <- "some_name"
foo
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# $some_name
# [1] 2
```

Comment: `names(foo) <- ""` results in `names(foo)` equal to the vector `"", NA`, so you need `names(foo) <- rep("", length(foo))` to set all names to `""`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Good point. I just got lucky with the small example. I've updated the answer. Kind of surprised recycling didn't happen in that case.